# I want to remove the cropping stage of profile image buddypress

Tags: wordpress, buddypress

I want to remove the cropping stage when I try to upload the avtar/profile image of user, can anyone suggest some solution, I just want a simple image upload function for profile pic. I'm using wp 4.5.3 and buddypress 2.5.3

my theme change avatar code is below

```
    <h4><?php _e( 'Change Profile Photo', 'buddypress' ); ?></h4>

<?php do_action( 'bp_before_profile_avatar_upload_content' ); ?>

<?php if ( !(int)bp_get_option( 'bp-disable-avatar-uploads' ) ) : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Your profile photo will be used on your profile and throughout the site. If there is a <a href="http://gravatar.com">Gravatar</a> associated with your account email we will use that, or you can upload an image from your computer.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

    <form action="#item-nav" method="post" id="avatar-upload-form" class="standard-form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

        <?php if ( 'upload-image' == bp_get_avatar_admin_step() ) : ?>

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'bp_avatar_upload' ); ?>
            <p><?php _e( 'Click below to select a JPG, GIF or PNG format photo from your computer and then click \'Upload Image\' to proceed.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

            <p id="avatar-upload">
                <input type="file" name="file" id="file" />
                <input type="submit" name="upload" class="button tiny radius" id="upload" value="<?php _e( 'Upload Image', 'buddypress' ); ?>" />
                <input type="hidden" name="action" id="action" value="bp_avatar_upload" />
            </p>

            <?php if ( bp_get_user_has_avatar() ) : ?>
                <p><?php _e( "If you'd like to delete your current profile photo but not upload a new one, please use the delete profile photo button.", 'buddypress' ); ?></p>
                <p><a class="button edit" href="<?php bp_avatar_delete_link(); ?>" title="<?php esc_attr_e( 'Delete Profile Photo', 'buddypress' ); ?>"><?php _e( 'Delete My Profile Photo', 'buddypress' ); ?></a></p>
            <?php endif; ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

        <?php if ( 'crop-image' == bp_get_avatar_admin_step() ) : ?>

            <h5><?php _e( 'Crop Your New Avatar', 'buddypress' ); ?></h5>


            <img src="<?php bp_avatar_to_crop(); ?>" id="avatar-to-crop" class="avatar" alt="<?php _e( 'Avatar to crop', 'buddypress' ); ?>" />

            <div id="avatar-crop-pane">
                <img src="<?php bp_avatar_to_crop(); ?>" id="avatar-crop-preview" class="avatar" alt="<?php _e( 'Avatar preview', 'buddypress' ); ?>" />
            </div>

            <input type="submit" class="button small radius" name="avatar-crop-submit" id="avatar-crop-submit" value="<?php _e( 'Crop Image', 'buddypress' ); ?>" />

            <input type="hidden" name="image_src" id="image_src" value="<?php bp_avatar_to_crop_src(); ?>" />
            <input type="hidden" id="x" name="x" />
            <input type="hidden" id="y" name="y" />
            <input type="hidden" id="w" name="w" />
            <input type="hidden" id="h" name="h" />

            <?php wp_nonce_field( 'bp_avatar_cropstore' ); ?>

        <?php endif; ?>

    </form>

<?php else : ?>

    <p><?php _e( 'Your profile photo will be used on your profile and throughout the site. To change your profile photo, please create an account with <a href="http://gravatar.com">Gravatar</a> using the same email address as you used to register with this site.', 'buddypress' ); ?></p>

<?php endif; ?>

<?php do_action( 'bp_after_profile_avatar_upload_content' ); ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I did not try this

```
remove_action( 'wp_head', 'bp_core_add_cropper_inline_js' );
```

[Check this article](https://buddypress.org/support/topic/disable-avatar-crop/)